# Kurtosis of Normal Distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

I have a basic question about kurtosis and specific distributions.

> **Definition:** Let $Y$ be a random variable. $\mu_Y$ and $\sigma_Y$ denote $Y$'s mean and standard deviation respectively. Then, the kurtosis of the distribution of $Y$ is $\frac{E[(Y-\mu_Y)^4]}{\sigma_Y^4}$.

My textbook then says "the kurtosis of a normally distributed random variable is $3$." I am wondering whether only standard normal distribution has a kurtosis being 3, or any normal distribution has the same kurtosis, namely $3$. How can all normal distributions have the same kurtosis when standard deviations may vary?

Comment: To answer your last question, the definition of kurtosis is based on converting a normal distribution to standard form so that the result doesn't depend on the parameters of the original distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X=\frac{Y-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}$.  Then $E(\frac{(Y-\mu_Y)^4}{\sigma_Y^4})=E(X^4)=3$, since $X$ is standard normal.

Comment: Just to clarify @herbsteinberg's answer:  YES:  *every* normal distribution has kurtosis equal $3$.

Comment: How $E(X^4)=3$? Could you elaborate on how you reached the answer?

Comment: $E(X^4)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^4e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx=3$.  This is the fourth moment of a standard normal distribution.